# Windows batch - Delete files of certain age and type and list them

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-io

I'm looking for a solution to allow users to delete certain file type older than X days from a specific path.
I managed to create this batch file so far:

```
@echo off

set /p FileAge= Delete files older than this many days: 
set /p FileType= File type to delete. Seperate with comma. (mov, mxf...): 
set /p FilePath= Full path of files location: 

for %%G in (%FileType%,) do forfiles -p "%FilePath%" -s -m *%%G -d -%FileAge% -c "cmd /c echo @path"

Choice /M "These files will be deleted. Do you want to continue?"
If Errorlevel 1 Goto Yes
If Errorlevel 2 Goto No

:Yes
for %%G in (%FileType%,) do forfiles -p "%FilePath%" -s -m *%%G -d -%FileAge% -c "cmd /c del @path"

:No
exit

PAUSE
```

There are several things missing:

- In line 9 - **Choice /M "These files will be deleted. Do you want to
  continue?"** What would be the best way to count how many files are
  going to be deleted?
- I would like the batch to output a list of deleted files to a log file. Something like log_01312014.txt

Comment: I am still running Windows XP so I can't test your script because the `forfiles` command is not recognized. Anyway, I can suggest you to set the delayed expansion of the variables using the statement `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` before the `for` cycle: in this way you are able to update the variable that counts the operations done by the `forfiles` command. I also suggest to improve the syntax of the script using the `( )` characters to better define the "dependency" of the tasks inside both loops.

Comment: I added "setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion" but it didn't change anything. Still not counting. Thanks.

Comment: Your code is very broken. I suggest you get a single `forfiles` command working with `one filespec` first, and then add a loop.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by broken. Would appreciate if you can throw some sample "intact" code.

Comment: @o_ren Have you changed the `count` variable into a delayed expansion variable? While ordinary variables are defined through the `%` symbols, the delayed expansion ones are enclosed by the `!` symbols. A working counter inside a `for` loop is like the following statement: `set count=!count!+1`. You need to use the delayed expansion because the ordinary variables are updated only at the end of each command line while in this case you need to update it while the command is still running.

Comment: Can you please post an example of how that line would look with a Delayed expansion variable?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hello O_ren to Stack Overflow.

Assume you are using Windows 7 or later we will use a folder named `"Files"` to transfer desired file types inside `"To_Delete"` Folder + a log file with the name `"Log_%date%.txt"`

After that you can simply delete or keep your files inside `"To_Delete"` folder with del command.

in the example below this one liner solution will move ini files older than 7 days to our folder `"To_Delete"` and log the moved files.

```
  robocopy "C:\Files" "c:\Files\To_Remove" /mov *.ini /minage:7 >C:\Files\Log_%date:~-4,4%_%date:~-10,2%_%date:~-7,2%.txt
```

Comment: Windows XP users can **use Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools** at Microsoft website for free download.

Comment: Thanks @madoui20032003
What if I wanted to move the files straight to the trash?
What if I wanted to trash several file types at once?

Comment: Yes you have to add after `/mov` the file types you want separated by spaces like this for example `/mov *.ini *.dat  *.mp3` etc...

Comment: To move them directly to the trash use your recycle bin path.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome help! Can I make the source path, file type and file age a variable? Allow the user to set them as in the batch file above? Thanks.

Comment: For further reading visit:[Using Batch Files](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490869.aspx)

Comment: I figured out most of it. But I can't find anywhere how to allow the user to define multiple file formats. Something like "for %%G in (%mp3%,)". Thanks!